# WebSphere 8.5: Load application dependencies from repository

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I sure am not the first person to wonder, yet it is really hard to find information on my question.

At the company I work at, the servers run WebSphere 8.5. In order to cut down installation time and memory usage, we created some shared libraries, where we have copy-pasted the common dependencies of our applications. Now you can see, that these can easily cause big problems when changing versions.

We have a Nexus Repository however, where every dependency our applications use can be reached. Since in our gradle projects, we have those dependencies listed anyway, it only seems logical for WAS to download and put these dependencies on the classpath of the application at startup (or whenever it wants to).

Is there a way to tell WAS where to look for these dependencies (our repo server) and what files to download? Is there a better solution to the problem?

Comment: Had a look at what containers can do for you? Then there are ways you can put libraries in a separate layer to have them available at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this inside of the server at runtime. The best you can hope for is setting up the shared libraries during your deployment, single-sourced with your applications declared dependencies.

Comment: that sounds like a more painful way, but I see that one working. How would you start implementing something like this? Is there a gradle plugin that can do this? I'm not trying to be lazy, just looking for a best practise

Comment: would you think putting the dependencies in the `ear/lib` folder be a better solution? Based on our experiences, in this case deploy times don't increase (as much as having them in the war archives), but we don't know how much memory usage would increase